# Measure to display value based on amount conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

Could you help me design a DAX measure for displaying value based on conditions like:

(By selected date)

The measure will display "GREEN" if:

- RESULT is "pass"

The measure will display "RED" if:

- RESULT is "fail" and is the first time (from the selected dated).
- RESULT is "fail" after continuously 9 times of pass.

The measure will display "BLUE" if:

- RESULT is "fail" before continuously 9 times of pass.

For example from day 1 - 15, if day 1 was pass then the measure showed GREEN, after that day 3 was fail then showed RED (first time failed) and then had a continuous pass (GREEN) until day 13 was fail (RED, after continuously day 4-12 passes). Lastly, day 14 was pass then it was GREEN but day 15 was fail so the measure displayed BLUE.

The data looks like this below:   (MEASURE_COLOUR is the measure I want)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhmOm.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.